# Creating Wifi signal bars with Latex

Tags: latex, tikz

Does anyone know how to create the following icons with Latex (tikz i guess)

[image]

With some `newcommand` that I can choose the bars to be filled from 0 to 4 in the tex document.

Something like the command they define here: [In-line graphics in text to represent a loading bar for language skills in a CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238898/in-line-graphics-in-text-to-represent-a-loading-bar-for-language-skills-in-a-cv), but instead of circles plotting this wifi bars.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\wifi}[1][4]{%
  \colorlet{col1}{gray}%
  \colorlet{col2}{gray}%
  \colorlet{col3}{gray}%
  \colorlet{col4}{gray}%   
  \ifnum0<#1
    \colorlet{col1}{green}%
  \fi%
  \ifnum1<#1
    \colorlet{col2}{green}%
  \fi%
  \ifnum2<#1
    \colorlet{col3}{green}%
  \fi%
  \ifnum3<#1
    \colorlet{col4}{green}%
  \fi%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=0.05ex]
    \fill[col1] (0ex,0ex) rectangle ++(0.5ex,0.9ex);
    \fill[col2] (0.7ex,0ex) rectangle ++(0.5ex,1.05ex);
    \fill[col3] (1.4ex,0ex) rectangle ++(0.5ex,1.20ex);
    \fill[col4] (2.1ex,0ex) rectangle ++(0.5ex,1.35ex);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

test \wifi[0] \wifi[1] \wifi[2] \wifi[3] \wifi[4]

\Huge test \wifi


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Certainly looks great. Could you [edit] and explain the code a bit?